# TimeOut error from beforeAll in JEST Test file

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

//helper

```
import { ExampleModel } from '@models/Example/Example.model';
import User from '../../../models/User';
import { mAdmin, mUser } from './mock-data';
import { to } from '../../../../test/util';

async function createUser() {
  const user = new User(mUser);
  const { err, savedUser } = await to(user.save());

  return savedUser;
}

export { createUser };
```

//example.test.ts

```
    import httpClient from '../../../test/controller/httpClient';
import { to } from '../../../test/util';
import { createUser } from './test/helper';

describe('ExampleController', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const user = await createUser();
  }, 10000);

  describe('GET /example', () => {
    it('should return 200 OK', async () => {
      const { err, res } = await to(httpClient.get('/example'));
      expect(err).toBeNull();
      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    });
  });
});
```

I am trying to create a user before all tests in beforaAll in the above test file. But I am getting timeout error. What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

ErrorMessage

thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 10000 ms for a hook.
Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See [https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout.%22)

```
  4 |
  5 | describe('ExampleController', () => {
> 6 |   beforeAll(async () => {
    |   ^
  7 |     const user = await createUser();
  8 |   }, 10000);
  9 |
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? F.i. what happens in `import { to } from '../../../../test/util';`? Maybe you forgot to set a mock...